# Excel forumula: Slow min/max nested if

Tags: excel, performance, if-statement, nested, formula

I am using the following formula to find the maximum date where all conditions are met.

```
=MAX(IF(B:B=G2,IF(C:C=G3,IF(D:D=G4,A:A,FALSE),FALSE),FALSE))
```

Where columns B, C and D are filtered to match criteria then from the matching results the maximum date from column A is found.

It works but is extremely slow for large datasets. I'm sure there must be a better way but I can't find a way of returning multiple results from which I can then find the max or min.

Comment: Would maxifs() be quicker?

Comment: WOW yes. It is literally in the name but I have never used maxifs!! Thank you